# TypeError при вызове атрибутов

Tags: python, ооп

Осваиваю ООП, написал простую программу, но при вызове атрибутов name или age выходит TypeError. Вот сам код

```
from random import randrange
female_names = ['Zoy','Penny','Kate']
male_names = ['Joe','Gabe','Mike']

class human:
   def __init__(self,name,age):
      self.name = name
      self.age = age
class male(human):
   def hello(self):
      print('Hello')
class female(human):
   def hello(self):
      print('hello')

m = male(male_names[randrange(0,3)],randrange(10,40))
m.hello()
print(m.name())
print(m.age())
```

Буду очень благодарен за помощь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это же не функция. Чтобы получить атрибут, скобки не нужны.

```
print(m.name)
print(m.age)
```

Как вариант, можно в классе human реализовать методы для получения нужных атрибутов:

```
from random import randrange
female_names = ['Zoy','Penny','Kate']
male_names = ['Joe','Gabe','Mike']

class human:
   def __init__(self,name,age):
      self.name = name
      self.age = age
   def get_name(self):
       return self.name
   def get_age(self):
       return self.age
class male(human):
   def hello(self):
      print('Hello')
class female(human):
   def hello(self):
      print('hello')

m = male(male_names[randrange(0,3)],randrange(10,40))
m.hello()
print(m.get_name())
print(m.get_age())
```